# writing session if/else in CakePHP login action breaks

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm trying to add and if/else to a login action in CakePHP. The login action has a number of lines and when I add my if/else after the LoginValidate, the brackets for the login action now don't close properly.

The session does get written but, but when using the bracket highlighter in sublime text2, the top most bracket doesn't get highlighted. Here's the code. What I'm trying to do is write a session variable for KCFinder to 'true' if the user is not in the UserGroup 'Admin' and false if the user is in the UserGroup 'Admin'.

```
public function login() {
    print_r($this -> Session -> read());
    if ($this->request -> isPost()) {
        $this->User->set($this->data);                                  
        if($this->User->LoginValidate()) {
            $email  = $this->data['User']['email'];
            $password = $this->data['User']['password'];
            $user = $this->User->findByUsername($email);
            $UserGroup = $this->User->UserGroup;

            if (empty($user)) {
                $user = $this->User->findByEmail($email);
                if (empty($user)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect Email/Username or Password'));
                    return;
                }
            }
                //write session value for kcfinder
            if ($user['UserGroup']['name']='Admin') {
                $this -> Session -> write("kcfinder", "false");
                $_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled']=false; //config from ckfinder
            } else {
                $this -> Session -> write("kcfinder", "true");
                return;
            }   

            // check for inactive account
            if ($user['User']['id'] != 1 and $user['User']['active']==0) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry your account is not active, please contact to Administrator'));
                return;
            }
            // check for verified account
            if ($user['User']['id'] != 1 and $user['User']['email_verified']==0) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your registration has not been confirmed please verify your email or contact to Administrator'));
                return;
            }
            if(empty($user['User']['salt'])) {
                $hashed = md5($password);
            } else {
                $hashed = $this->UserAuth->makePassword($password, $user['User']['salt']);
            }

            if ($user['User']['password'] === $hashed) {
                if(empty($user['User']['salt'])) {
                    $salt=$this->UserAuth->makeSalt();
                    $user['User']['salt']=$salt;
                    $user['User']['password']=$this->UserAuth->makePassword($password, $salt);
                    $this->User->save($user,false);
                }
                $this->UserAuth->login($user);
                $remember = (!empty($this->data['User']['remember']));
                if ($remember) {
                    $this->UserAuth->persist('2 weeks');
                }
                $OriginAfterLogin=$this->Session->read('Usermgmt.OriginAfterLogin');
                $this->Session->delete('Usermgmt.OriginAfterLogin');
                $redirect = (!empty($OriginAfterLogin)) ? $OriginAfterLogin : LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL;
                $this->redirect($redirect);
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect Email/Username or Password'));
                return;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

additional points:

1) this code comes from a user management plugin from: http://usermgmt.ektasoftwares.com

2) the section that I added is:

```
                //write session value for kcfinder
        if ($user['UserGroup']['name']='Admin') {
            $this -> Session -> write("kcfinder", "false");
            $_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled']=false; //config from ckfinder
        } else {
            $this -> Session -> write("kcfinder", "true");
            return;
        }
```

The result of adding my session section is that the two top most brackets don't properly highlight (again using the highlight plugin in sublime text2)

Thanks for the comments and input.

Comment: You should at least post the version you cannot get to work. How should we figure out what you are doing wrong, if you don't even show us what you did?

Comment: I think your login method should have around 4 lines of code (not 1000). there is definitely room for some serious refactoring here.

Comment: Are you actually using the Auth component? Because you are writing stuff that is handled by that component for you. Like roles, sessions, constraints like "active == 1". BTW you wrote "=" instead of "==" once. Auth component link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I added two points on the user management plugin I'm using and which section I added that seems to break the two top most brackets. when I print_r on the session, the UserGroup does get printed, which is why I was using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check your comparison

This is an assignment - not a comparison:

```
if ($user['UserGroup']['name']='Admin') {
```

I.e. after this the value of `$user['UserGroup']['name']` is *set* to true, and the code will always enter this if block. This is probably the intention:

```
if ($user['UserGroup']['name'] === 'Admin') {
```

Errors like this are a lot easier to spot with consistent whitespace (the code in the question is quite varied). You can also avoid them using this style:

```
if ('Admin' === $user['UserGroup']['name']) {
```

Which "works" because if you make the same mistake you get a parse error rather than an assignment:

```
if ('Admin' = $user['UserGroup']['name']) {
```

### Some bonus comments

#### That's a lot of code

This login function is pretty big (and it references more code, that isn't shown). It could be a lot simpler. For example from [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) (be sure to compare to the book for the version of cake you're using):

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

There are some additional bits of logic in the code in the question - but there are also chunks of code duplicating what the Auth login function does.

### Use CakePHP

if you're using CakePHP - *use* CakePHP. This line:

```
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled']=false; //config from ckfinder
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$this->Session->write('KCFINDER.disabled', false);
```

Being consistent, again, makes code easier to read and ultimately easier to maintain.

Comment: thanks. I changed the operator to a comparison. After testing the session that's written is correct. However, I still have the problem where the two top most brackets for this action aren't highlighted and I don't understand why. Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sur what you refer to with "the two top most brackets" if your editor doesn't highlight code correctly there are a number of possible reasons - try formatting the code =)

Comment: I mention it because I was concerned something might not work as expected. Also, it didn't make sense that this if/else would cause the brackets to become broken. I'll take your advice and spend some more time on google to better understand/answer my question. thanks again

Comment: thanks AD7six, I do appreciate your comments. I didn't write the login code, it's from a plugin but I do understand that it's long. I'll consider my approach. cheers